# How to correctly estimate the percentage change of two columns considering different indexes in the series with pandas? Python related

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, debugging, valueerror

Say I have the following df called `df_trading_pair`:

```
    Start Date           Open Price     High Price  Low Price   Close Price End Date
0   2022-07-20 08:00:00  0.19277        0.19324     0.19225     0.19324     2022-07-20 08:04:59.999
1   2022-07-20 08:05:00  0.19321        0.194       0.1932      0.19388     2022-07-20 08:09:59.999
2   2022-07-20 08:10:00  0.19387        0.195       0.19387     0.19489     2022-07-20 08:14:59.999
3   2022-07-20 08:15:00  0.19496        0.19628     0.19495     0.19626     2022-07-20 08:19:59.999
4   2022-07-20 08:20:00  0.19625        0.20406     0.19625     0.2035      2022-07-20 08:24:59.999
```

I have been trying to figure out a simple way to get the percentage change of **the first 4** elements in `Open Price` column vs **the last 4** elements in `Close Price`, so I end up getting the following output in a `new_df`:

```
 Close Price vs Open Price % change
0                            0.0057
1                            0.0087
2                            0.0123
3                            0.0438
dtype: float64
```

At first, I thought the following sentence should've worked perfectly, after all both arrays would have 4 elements and would contain exactly the values that I need:

```
new_df["Close Price vs Open Price % change"] = (df_trading_pair["Close Price"][1:]-df_trading_pair["Open Price"][:-1])/df_trading_pair["Open Price"][:-1]
```

However, that sentence ended up throwing this output:

```
 Close Price vs Open Price % change
0                               NaN
1                          0.003468
2                          0.005261
3                          0.006668
4                               NaN
dtype: float64
```

Which I don't get why, I also tried this other sentence:

```
new_df["Close Price vs Open Price % Change"] = [(y-x)/x*100 for x in df_trading_pair["Open Price"][:-1] for y in df_trading_pair["Close Price"][1:]]
```

Which in my opinion should also have done what I was looking for, but unfortunately it did not and threw the following error:

> ```
> ValueError: Length of values (16) does not match length of index (5)
> ```

So, I would like to get some assistance here, what else could I do in order to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), else pandas will realign your indices:

```
df['Close Price'].shift(-1).sub(df['Open Price']).div(df['Open Price'])[:-1]
```

Output:

```
0    0.005758
1    0.008695
2    0.012328
3    0.043804
dtype: float64
```

Your approach would work with numpy arrays as there is no index realignment:

```
c = df['Close Price'][1:].to_numpy()
o = df['Open Price'][:-1].to_numpy()

out = (c-o)/o
```

Output:

```
array([0.00575816, 0.0086952 , 0.01232785, 0.04380386])
```